# Edit 14 day weather forecast Excel VBA to include precipitation

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

I found the code below which works nicely and I think I can repurpose it for my needs, but does not include the precipitation. I'm relatively new to HTML so having trouble understanding what each line of code's purpose is. I've gone to the website and looked at the elements and console but can't find "p[data-testid='wxPhrase']" or the word 'children' or 'child'.

I presumed precipitation was just another child so tried adding lines like these after editing the column headers in the first sub:

```
Results(r + 1, 3) = Children(r).FirstChild.innerText 

Results(r + 1, 4) = Children(r).PreviousSibling.PreviousSibling.PreviousSibling.FirstChild.innerText
```

but it gives Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method. I appreciate very much some help and education. Thanks, in advance!

```
Sub MiamiWeather()
Dim Data As Variant
Data = MiamiWeatherData

Range("A1:B1").Value = Array("Date", "Temperature")
Range("A2").Resize(UBound(Data), 2).Value = Data
    
End Sub

Function MiamiWeatherData()
    Const URL = "https://weather.com/weather/tenday/l/3881cd527264bc7c99b6b541473c0085e75aa026b6bd99658c56ad9bb55bd96e"
    Dim responseText As String
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .send
    responseText = .responseText
End With

Dim Document As HTMLDocument
Set Document = CreateObject("HTMLFILE")
Document.body.innerHTML = responseText

Dim Children As IHTMLDOMChildrenCollection
Set Children = Document.querySelectorAll("p[data-testid='wxPhrase']")
Dim Results As Variant
ReDim Results(1 To Children.Length, 1 To 2)
Dim r As Long

For r = 0 To Children.Length - 1
    Results(r + 1, 1) = Children(r).PreviousSibling.PreviousSibling.FirstChild.innerText
    Results(r + 1, 2) = Children(r).PreviousSibling.FirstChild.innerText
Next

MiamiWeatherData = Results
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want the percentage, you need to resize the array to hold an extra dimension then add an extra selector within the loop. That selector can select by attribute = value and will need to work off `.Children(r).PreviousSibling`. Assuming, you have a still maintained Microsoft set-up you can chain querySelector at this point as shown below.

---

For older versions e.g., <= Windows 7 then use `Results(r + 1, 3) = Children(r).PreviousSibling.Children(2).Children(0).Children(1).innerText`

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub MiamiWeather()
    Dim Data As Variant
    Data = MiamiWeatherData

    Range("A1:C1").value = Array("Date", "Temperature", "Precipitation")
    Range("A2").Resize(UBound(Data), 3).value = Data
    
End Sub

Function MiamiWeatherData()
    Const URL = "https://weather.com/weather/tenday/l/3881cd527264bc7c99b6b541473c0085e75aa026b6bd99658c56ad9bb55bd96e"
    Dim responseText As String
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .send
        responseText = .responseText
    End With

    Dim Document As HTMLDocument
    Set Document = CreateObject("HTMLFILE")
    Document.body.innerHTML = responseText

    Dim Children As IHTMLDOMChildrenCollection
    Set Children = Document.querySelectorAll("p[data-testid='wxPhrase']")
    Dim Results As Variant
    ReDim Results(1 To Children.length, 1 To 3)
    Dim r As Long

    For r = 0 To Children.length - 1
        Results(r + 1, 1) = Children(r).PreviousSibling.PreviousSibling.FirstChild.innerText
        Results(r + 1, 2) = Children(r).PreviousSibling.FirstChild.innerText
        Results(r + 1, 3) = Children(r).PreviousSibling.querySelector("[data-testid=PercentageValue]").innerText
    Next

    MiamiWeatherData = Results
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help and the explanation on why the solution works QHarr!  I'll be experimenting to educated myself =D